# Help with combinations problem?

Tags: combinatorics

> Initially there are $m$ balls in one bag, and $n$ in the other, where $m,n>0$. Two different operations are allowed:
>
> a) Remove an equal number of balls from each bag;
>   b) Double the number of balls in one bag.
>
> Is it always possible to empty both bags after a finite sequence of operations?
>
> Operation b) is now replaced with
>
> b') Triple the number of balls in one bag.
>
> Is it now always possible to empty both bags after a finite sequence of operations?

This is question 4 on Round $1$ of the $2011/2012$ British Mathematical Olympiad.

I suck at combinatorics and the like but need to practise to try and improve my competition mathematics. If anyone could give me a hint on where to start I'd be most grateful :D

EDIT: Never mind guys, I just completely mis-read the question. I thought it said you had to double the numbers of balls in both bags. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, if $m=n$, just take everything. Otherwise, apply operation (a) to reduce the smaller bag to a single ball, and let $a$ be the number of balls in the other bag at that point. Double the $1$ and take $1$ ball from each bag, so that you now have $a-1$ balls in one bag and $1$ in the other. Repeat until you have one ball in each bag and then empty the bags with operation (a).

For the second question I conjecture that $m=1$, $n=2$ is a position from which the bags cannot be emptied, though I don’t immediately see an argument.

**Added:** The conjecture is correct, and the other answer was on the right track. Suppose that $m$ and $n$ have opposite parity.Subtracting the same amount from each leaves two numbers of opposite parity, and multiplying a number by $3$ does not change its parity, so you always have two numbers of opposite parity. In particular, you cannot empty both bags.

Comment: @user78416: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part...

Let $m>n$

Remove $n-1$ balls from each bag so that you have $m-n+1$ balls in one bag and $1$ ball in the other bag.

Now repeat the algorithm of doubling the balls in the bag which has $1$ ball and then taking away $1$ from each bag till you have $1$ ball in each bag. Finally remove $1$ ball from each bag and you have emptied them in finite number of steps.

For the second part

Again suppose $m>n$

Remove $n-1$ balls from each bag so that you have $m-n+1$ balls in one bag and $1$ ball in the other bag.

Now repeat the algorithm of tripling the balls in the bag which has $1$ ball and then taking away $2$ from each bag. If $2|(m-n)$, then you'll end up with $1$ ball in each bag in some steps. Otherwise you'll end up with $2$ balls in one bag and $1$ ball in the other bag and **it seems like** no matter what you do from here, you'll always end up with this arrangement.

Hence, in the second part, **it may be conjectured** that the bags cannot be emptied in finite steps if $m-n\equiv 1\pmod2$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help but I misread the question! xD Makes it a lot simpler ^.^

Comment: You’ve not actually proved that there is no solution starting from $m=1,n=2$: your *no matter what you do from here* assertion requires proof.